# How to configure the message size for a WCF web role (Currently getting HTTP error code 500)

Tags: .net, wcf, azure

Thank you all!

We were able to **solve** this problem simply by changing the binding element name from "basicHttpBinding" to "webHttpBinding".

Silly, I know..

---

Hello,

I am trying to implement a web role using WCF, that will receive JSON objects and store them in the Azure storage. During the integration tests I got a 400 error code. I then discovered that WCF has a very small message size (~65535), and that I need to configure it to be larger. The configuration I am currently using causes a 500 error code whenever I try to post an HTTP request to my service (the request never reaches my code).

The Web.config file I am using looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <system.web>

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel> 

    <diagnostics>

      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxSizeOfMessageToLog="5000000" />

      <endToEndTracing activityTracing="false" />

    </diagnostics>

    <services>

      <service name="MyWebRole.RequestHandler" behaviorConfiguration="RequestHandlerbehavior">

        <endpoint address="http://localhost:9001/" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="conf" name="MyDefaultEndpoint"

                                contract="MyWebRole.IRequestHandler" />

      </service>

    </services>   

    <bindings>

      <basicHttpBinding>

        <binding name="conf" maxBufferSize="5000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000" useDefaultWebProxy="true">

          <readerQuotas maxDepth="5000000" maxStringContentLength="5000000" maxArrayLength="5000000" maxBytesPerRead="5000000" maxNameTableCharCount="5000000" />

        </binding>

      </basicHttpBinding>

    </bindings>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />

    <behaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>

        <behavior name="RequestHandlerbehavior">

          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />

          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />

        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />

  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Can you please help me get my requests through to my WCF service?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact error message? You can probably find it in the event log on the server.

Comment: The thought occurs that if you are using azure storage, why use JSON? There are denser serializers... That would reduce the payload somewhat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried increasing the message receive size on your binding?  Such as...

maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576"